# Unable to set property 'URL' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I have a window with a javascript variable and a function defined:

```
// in window 1:
<SCRIPT>
var someVariable = "hello, world";
function myFunc(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

I open a second window from a link in the first window, and grab a reference to the opener:

```
// in window 2:
var windowOpener = window.opener;
```

That second window opens a third, and it contains the following script:

```
// in window 3:
alert(window.parent.windowOpener.someVariable);
```

The above line correctly prints "hello, world". However, I then try to execute the function on window 1, thusly:

```
// in window 3:
window.parent.windowOpener.myFunc("hi, world");
```

That throws the following exception:

"Unable to set property 'URL' of undefined or null reference"

My environment is javascript, Velocity, and Struts, so these windows are being opened not by "window.open" calls, but by calling action classes that forward to vm files.  My guess is that has something to do with it, but why would the variable reference work but not the function call?

Comment: You are not setting `URL` anywhere in the code you provided, so your guess in the last paragraph is quite right.

Comment: Thank you.  What's odd is that I don't set the URL anywhere at all.  What you're seeing is just pure javascript -- it doesn't leverage velocity or struts at all in this portion of the code.  It seems that it's the underlying js scripting engine (IE 11 in compatibility mode) that is doing something.  I haven't been able to find a reference to this behavior anywhere.

Comment: And "if (window.parent.windowOpener.myFunc)" evaluates to true!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the function to a variable, ie

```
// in window 1:
<SCRIPT>
var someVariable = "hello, world";
var myFunc = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

It's hard to say otherwise based on the code you provided, since you're not setting a URL property anywhere in there.. May be a config issue with your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion ... but I still get the same exception.  The "window.parent.windowOpener" variable clearly holds a valid reference to an open window, but I'm unable to execute functions -- I can only access variables.

Comment: My guess is that there is something weird with your vm files configuration like you stated at the end of your question.. Hard to say without seeing more code as nothing you wrote appears incorrect :\